# How to rewrite Raw SQL Query (MySQL) with Django ORM query?

Tags: python, sql, django

How to rewrite next Raw SQL Query (MySQL) with Django ORM query?

```
mysql> select author_id, 
              count(*) c 
        from library_books 
       group by author_id 
      having c>2 
       limit 3;

+---------------+----+

|     author_id | c  |

+---------------+----+

|             0 | 39 |

|          1552 | 17 |

|          1784 |  8 |

+---------------+-----
```

Answer (score 2):

First, [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) an author queryset with the number of books.

```
from django.db.models import Count
authors = Author.objects.annotate(num_books=Count('librarybook')
```

You haven't shown your Django models, so I've had to guess that 'librarybook' is the correct name for the reverse relationship.

Then filter on the `num_books` to find authors with more than two books.

```
authors = Author.objects.annotate(num_books=Count('librarybook').filter(num_books__gt=2)
```

Finally, slice the queryset to limit it to 3 results.

```
authors = Author.objects.annotate(num_books=Count('librarybook').filter(num_books__gt=2)[:3]
```

You can then loop through the resulting authors and access the number of books.

```
for author in authors:
    print author.name, author.num_books
```